# Laravel queue to store data

Tags: laravel-5, queue

I wanna try to store data into database via database queue Laravel.

But I always get this error "Undefined offset: 0"

this is my controller :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $order = new Order;
        $order->code = $request->code;
        $order->created_at = $request->created_at;

        $this->dispatch(new SalesOrder($order));
    }
```

and this is my SalesOrder Jobs :

```
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order= $order;
    }


    public function handle()
    {
         $this->order->save();
    }
```

is there something wrong in my code? Please somebody help me fix this issue. Than's anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of pass Order object pass in job order data, And the in job save order.

Controller code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data['code'] = $request->code;
    $data['created_at'] = $request->created_at;

    $this->dispatch(new SalesOrder($data));
}
```

Job code

```
protected $data;

public function __construct(array $data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}


public function handle(Order $order)
{
    if (!$order->craete($this->data)) {
        // when not saved try again
        $this->release();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Almaida Jody Are you try this??

Comment: @AlmaidaJody Jody It is your expected result??

Comment: im sorry for this late reply.. i've try and it return the same error again.. "Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: can you tell me what exactly I have to do, to save data via laravel queue?

Comment: even I just do 

    public function handle(Order $order)
    {
        
        dd($order);exit();
    }
in my handle function, it will return "Undefined Offset [0]".

Comment: should I do the save prses in the Job construct?

Comment: try befor **$data['code'] = $request->code;** dd($request->all()); What is it?

Comment: there is no problem if I "dd" in construct.. all data return properly.. but whenever I do something in handle function, something went wrong..

Comment: and if I do this in the construct, 

public function __construct(array $data)
    {
      $this->data = $data;
      
      Order::create($this->data);
    }
there is no problem when I do this.. but is this right?

Comment: No it is no right. Your saving action must be done in handle method??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173044/discussion-between-davit-and-almaida-jody).

Comment: the problem is assync queue or not, so I've to delete the "use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;". thank's for the advice Davit

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
$order = new Order;
$order->code = $request->code;
$order->created_at = $request->created_at;
```

inside your job so it looks like this

```
protected $order;
protected $request

public function __construct($request)
{
  $this->order = new Order;
  $this->request = $request;
}


public function handle()
{
  $this->order->code = $request->code;
  $this->order->created_at = $request->created_at;
  $this->order->save();
}
```

and in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $this->dispatch(new SalesOrder($request));
}
```

This should work. Did not test this am writing on my phone.

Comment: now it return an error like this "Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"